# How to create LVM also using the partition that has the whole system on it?

Tags: partitioning, root, lvm

Ubuntu Server Zesty x64. The whole system is on the `/dev/nbd0` mounted as `/`. The second volume is `/dev/nbd1` which is empty. Now I'd like to shrink `/dev/nbd0` to 5GB (now it has 50GB), create `/dev/nbd2` from the empty space and merge it as LVM with `/dev/nbd1`.

Is it possible to do on a running system via SSH, without any excessive "hacks"? Or am I completely wrong, so it cannot be done. Is there any other way?

Comment: The LVM part can be done over ssh, but not the initial "shrink".

Answer (score 0):

One "advantage" of LVM is that you can always add to it running live, so that part you can do over ssh.

You can not downsize the initial "/dev/nbd0 mounted as /" live or over ssh , the partition must be unmounted to reduce the size.

Note : With LVM it is easy to increase the size, but reducing the size can sometimes be difficult or impossible.

To decrease the size of a LVM see - https://www.linuxtechi.com/reduce-size-lvm-partition/ or similar. Just make a backup first ;)

IMO it is faster, easier, and more reliable to make a new, smaller LVM partition and copy the data over rather then downsize a LVM.